# Skroll issue with multiple relative keyframes

Tags: skrollr

I'm using [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) and trying to set multiple relative keyframes. This doesn't work for me at the moment.

```
data-bottom-top="opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0,0)" data-top-top="opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0,0,0)" data-top-botttom="transform:translate3d(0,50%,0) data-100p-top-botttom="transform:translate3d(0,50%,0)"
```

Have been cracking my head over this for the past few days. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: All values need a unit, e.g. `%`

Comment: Thanks Prinzhorn but that still didn't work for me. Strange this is some elements using translate3d do not units for 0 but they animate fine.

Comment: Please create a demo page.

Comment: Hi Prinzhorn, I'll try to put up a demo as I can't release my client's link. But I think I've figured it out: I understand that you can't mix px and % values in an element but it seems that you can't mix px and % throughout the whole document.

Comment: @Prinzhorn, here's a [demo with a single screen](http://playtmn.net/beta/index.html). All 3 elements are supposed to scroll up.

Comment: Seems like you're working on the demo right now (the page changes during refresh). Please include the unminified skrollr and tell me when I can visit the page again.

Comment: @Prinzhorn I've uploaded the unminified skrollr and am not making any further updates. Thanks very much for taking a look.

Comment: The third value of `translate3d` cannot be a percentage value. That's not a skrollr thing, but just invalid CSS. You can just use `translate` anyway, since you're not doing anything in 3d.

Comment: @Prinzhorn thanks, I'll try that. I'm building the page based on several "slides". Is there a method to trigger a function to jump to a slide on mobile? I realized scripts like scrollTo do not work with Skrollr on mobile.

Comment: skrollr has `setScrollTop` and `animateTo`

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the question fully, you must use the same units for each argument:

```
data-bottom-top="opacity:0;transform:translate3d(100%,0%,0)" 
data-top-top="opacity:1;transform:translate3d(0%,0%,0)" 
data-top-botttom="transform:translate3d(0%,50%,0) 
data-100p-top-botttom="transform:translate3d(0%,50%,0)"
```

See these:

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/134
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/315